# Is it possible to remove an instance of an object from memory and restore it later in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

My question is a bit vague so let me elaborate. I'm a beginner programmer working on my first flash game which for the point of this question is a side-scrolling platformer like mario for example. Unlike a traditional platformer though, the level will continue indefinitely until a player dies or quits the game. The level is tilebased and will be generated automatically through a array which specifies what object is in each tile( or 0 if there is no object). In order to ensure my game doesn't automatically crash from excessive objects I will generate more of the map( by creating new instances of objects)  as the player progresses so that as the player move right the map is generated just past the edge of the screen.

Now back to the matter at hand, I'm guessing that once the player gets to a certain point in the game it will start to slow down because more and more objects are being created.
I assume the solution to this problem would be to remove the instances to the left of the screen as the player progresses however the problem with this is I need the player to have the ability to go back through the level.

So my question is: how can i 'delete' or remove the instances from memory, so my game doesn't slow down, but also restore the instance when the player moves into a certain proximity of where that instance is (or was).

Note: Currently aside from the player the only object i have in the game is the 'Wall' object all instances of which are stored in the 'Wallarray' array which i currently only use to reference instances of a Wall for collision detection

Comment: Are you concerned with retaining info about your off-screen objects only DURING game play, or also BETWEEN gameplay sessions? I.o.w., do you want to allow players to start the game again tomorrow where they left off today?

Comment: You have to understand that even though you might be saving CPU cycles by removing elements from the game, you will only be able to store as much information about visited areas as your RAM can hold. From there you can pass that data off to a file on your HD or to a database somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment, but either way it may be the same answer. Read up on the SharedObject class and do some simple experiments using SharedObjects to write info about objects to disk, and to read that info back.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to split game model from its view. You'll have the whole level model stored in a separate class and a view which renders visible model's part onto the stage. Rendering engine will remove visual objects that are out of the screen as well as create visual objects which become visible. Your model will dispatch some events to notify your view about its changes. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use object pooling: When your objects are not visible anymore you can put them in a temporary array an when you need a new object, instead of create a new you can get one from this array.

here an example of object with his pool:

```
package
{

    public class Pooled extends MovieClip
    {
        /** the array containg objects created and not used **/
        protected static var _pool      :Vector.<Pooled>;
        /** the number of objects in the pool **/
        protected static var _nbItems   :int;

        public function Pooled()
        {

        }

        /** a function to dispose the object **/
        public function dispose():void
        {
            // do what you want here for release memory
        }

        /** the function to call to release the object and return it to the pool **/
        public function release():void
        {
            // do what you want here, stop animations, remove from parent, remove listeners ...
            // put it in the pool
            _pool[_nbItems++] = this;
        }

        /** a static function to initialize the object and to create the pool **/
        public static function init():void
        {
            _pool       = new Vector.<Pooled>();
            _nbItems    = 0;
        }

        /** a static function to get an object from the pool **/
        public static function get():Pooled
        {
            var a   :Pooled;
            if( _nbItems > 0 )
            {
                a = _pool.pop();
                _nbItems--;
            }
            else
            {
                a = new Pooled();
            }
            return a;
        }

        /** a static function to destroy objects and the pool **/
        public static function dispose():void
        {
            for( var i:int = 0; i<_nbItems; ++i )   _pool[i].dispose();
            _pool.length = 0;
            _pool = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to call first the static init method to create the pool array.
After that instead of create object using `new Pooled();`, use `Pooled.get();`, it will return you item from the pool if available and if not, it will create a new one.
When you don't want your object anymore, you can call `release()` function and the object will be moved to the pool.

Using this technique, the maximum object in memory will be the maximum displayed object at the same time. And you avoid the time of creating new objects when your pool contain object.

Hope this could help you.